# surround words with brackets when a comma is reached in a String

Tags: java, regex

I am 90% there with a regular expression but i would really appreciate some help in finalizing it.

I start with the following String.

```
String toiletDer= "TOILET, BOG, PUBLIC CONVENIENCE";
```

//formated the code.

and i need it to become `"({BOG}|{TOILET}|{PUBLIC CONVENIENCE})"`

My regex so far is.

```
toiletDer.replaceAll("(\\p{Alpha}+)", "{$1}|").replace(",", "")
```

it produces the `following`

```
"{TOILET}| {BOG}| {PUBLIC}| {CONVENIENCE}|"
```

I only want words to be surrounded in a new set of {} when a comma is reached in the String and not a new word which is how it currently works.

Comment: Why not make it simpler? replaceAll(", ", "}|{") And then just add the leading ({ and trailing }) to the string seperately?

Comment: In your example you are saying that `TOILET, BOG,` should became `{BOG}|{TOILET}|` (notice the order of words)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
String string = "({" + toiletDer.replaceAll(",\\s*","}|{") + "})"
```

be easier?

Answer (score 1):

To include spaces in your matching part you can use `[\\p{Alpha}\\s]+`. To match `|` at the end you can use `\\|$`, so maybe try this way

```
toiletDer.replaceAll("\\s*([\\p{Alpha}\\s]+)", "{$1}|").replaceAll(",|\\|$", "")
```

I also added `\\s*` at start of first regex to remove spaces at start of `{ BOG}`.

### Update

If you want to surround result with parenthesis you can add them at start and end. Also `\p{Alpha}` doesn't contain `.` since it is non alphanumeric character. To include it in your regex you can add it to `[]` character class.
Here is updated code.

```
"(" + toiletDer.replaceAll("\\s*([\\p{Alpha}\\s]+)", "{$1}|")
    .replaceAll(",|\\|$", "") + ")";
```

Comment: @Mike I see in your question you want also to surround your output with parenthesis. Should I include it in my answer or you know how to do it? :)

Comment: Hi that would be great. Also is there anyway that the regular expression can change slightly because if the String is BHS, B.H.S then the output is {BHS}|{B}|.{H}|.{S} when ideally it should be {BHS}| {B.H.S} - thanks again.

Comment: @Mike I updated my answer. It should do what you want but I would recommend taking a look at James` Robinson answer. It simplifies your regex because it just replaces commas (and spaces after them) with `}|{` so `Abc, de fg,h.i.j` will become `Abc}|{de fg}|{h.i.j`. Now all you need to do is add `{(` and `)}` at start and end. IMHO it is worth to give it a try.

Comment: @Mike glad you liked James` answer. It was really best choice here :)

Comment: The `{$1}` is an amazing thing. I've got what I was looking for (thanks for the awesome regex!), but don't know how the `{$1}` works. @Pshemo can you please give pointers? :)

Comment: @Sufian In replacement part `$x` represents content of group indexed as `x`. We are creating groups with parenthesis, and they are indexed based on ordering of opening parenthesis `(`. For instance if we want to swap each two characters we can put first in one group, second in another, and use reversed content of those groups in replacement like `"abcd".replaceAll("(\\w)(\\w)", "$2$1")` which will create string `"badc"`.

Comment: @Pshemo that was helpful. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
toiletDer.replaceAll("([^,]+)", "{$1}|").replace(",", "")
```

This supposes that you only have words and commas, and not special or other caracters.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all the commas with a `}|{`, and add a `{` at the start and a `}` at the end.

But this still doesn't sort the words like you want, i.e. you would get `{TOILET}|{BOG}|{PUBLIC CONVENIENCE}` and not `{BOG}|{TOILET}|{PUBLIC CONVENIENCE}`